# Write test case for require() in angular

Tags: html, angular, image, angular-components

I have added require to refer a svg image in html from component because of whihc my tests are failing. PLease help me with test cases

```
declare var require: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['test.component.scss'],

})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    referenceImage = require("./book.svg");

}
```

```
    <button mat-icon-button >
                <a class="reference-route" routerLink="reference" title="Reference">
                    <img class="reference-image" [src]="referenceImage" />
                </a>
    </button>
```

the code structure:

```
project
   ----------apps
       -------------test-frontend
           -------------src
               -------------assets
   ----------libs
        ----------shared
             ----------test
                ----------test.component.ts
```

Comment: First things first, **why would you do that** ? That's a terrible way of using an image

Comment: I agree. But I have tried all the other options to show image all of them are not working.

Comment: Then you clearly did something wrong ... Put your image in the `assets` folder, then write `<svg:svg src="assets/book.svg" class="reference-image">`. If you keep your image here, you will lose it at build time.

Comment: I have already tried to add image in the assets. The image url turns to localhost:4200/assets/book.svg and it fails to found the image 404

Comment: Then use relative pathing, `./assets/book.svg`, and be sure to have the correct path. And I have the example right in front of me, in my own application, showing that it works. If it doesn't work on your end, then you surely did something wrong !

Comment: the code structure is kind of different for us, this is might be the reason why it doesnt work: Can you please check thecode structure in the question I have jsut added

Comment: Well yeah, no wonder it doesn't work ... your path is relative to the `index.html` file, I'll let you find the correct one !